# I have 100 separated images of a letter "F". How can I align every letter F + Export at the same image format?

Tags: photoshop, photoshop-script

As the title says, I have approximately 100 different images with the letter F (black letter, white background) on it.

Can someone help me find a workflow to effectively align each F letter (eather on the top bar of each "F" or in the top left corner) AND exporting every image at the same size and format (lets say a square image).

I do not understand Photoshop as I never had to use it, so your help would be a huge time saver for me.

Thanks !

*What did I tried ?
Not much. To cut a long story short: I inserted the 100 images as layers (via the scripts menu), select the first layer, select by object, place the letter F in the corner with the grid magnetism, crop manually.

The problem is that with 100 layers it's long and rather approximate, also cropping the first layer also crops the "background zone" for the others layers making the letter impossible to see when I activate the next layer, and when I activate certain layers I can't even find the image (adding the 100 images via the script creates a kind of huge area in which the images are scattered, and sometimes some of them seem to fall out)...
*

Comment: "What did I tried ? Not much" - this is not a good start... So, let's ignore the 100 files. What would you do to a single image in order to align it to the top left?

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you need to repeatedly do the same thing to a bunch of pictures and export each one. In photoshop there are Actions, and when you create a new action, you can hit the record button, and take whatever steps you need to do, and then click stop. You can then trigger the action and it's steps on whatever shortcut key you set it as.

For example, I needed to make a puzzle in photoshop, and I had a photo with a puzzle outline on a layer above. I figured out how to cut out a piece, and instead of cutting each piece and exporting them by hand, I created an action where I just had to click on the puzzle piece area, and then the hotkey, and it'd do all the work of cutting it out and exporting it. Sounds really similar to your situation.